# how to cache sencha touch files to improve performance

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have developed one sencha touch app and whenever i open into mobile browser it loads all the script every time i open it.

so is there a way to cache the required js files and css so that performance will be faster and it doesn't load the files everytime ?

Answer (score 1):

The way is to utilize HTML5 cache manifest file that lists rules of caching for files in concern. There is a good tutorial on how to implement it here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?102054-SOLVED-How-make-a-sencha-touch-app-offline-usable-with-html5-cache-manifest